# Django ORM: Apply ordering to raw query sets

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Here is the raw query set Django ORM:

```
ob = Shop.objects.raw('SELECT * from shops GROUP BY
 (duplicate_field_name) having COUNT(*) = 1 ORDER BY some_field')

listorder = ["check_in","check_out","location"]
```

This listorder part is dynamic. I don't know how it ll be. It ll change the ordering from time to time & one more thing can't apply ordering on raw query sets because I want the whole data for other purpose.After that only i can apply ordering. 
Here want ordering by the list "listorder".

`mObj = ob.order_by[*listorder]`.

In above facing error like can't apply ordering to raw query sets. 
Anyone having any idea?

Comment: Do you mean that check_in, check_out and location are members of the Shop model and you want to order the raw resultset by that?

Comment: Does it have to be raw SQL? Maybe you could use [Django's extra() clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra), which does support an order_by kwarg.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a raw queryset to be ordered by different fields, you can add them to the ORDER BY clause.

```
ob = Shop.objects.raw('SELECT * from shops GROUP BY
 (duplicate_field_name) having COUNT(*) = 1 ORDER BY check_in, check_out, location')
```

if you want the order to be reversed for a particular field you can change it as

```
ob = Shop.objects.raw('SELECT * from shops GROUP BY
 (duplicate_field_name) having COUNT(*) = 1 ORDER BY check_in, check_out DESC, location')
```

If the ordering is going to be dynamic, you can create the querystring dynamically.

```
qs = ''SELECT * from shops GROUP BY
 (duplicate_field_name) having COUNT(*) = 1'

# some other code here to decide what your ordering is example
order_fields = ['id','location','check_in','check_out']

qs = qs + "ORDER BY " + ",".join(order_fields)
```

Then you can query as before

```
Shop.objects.raw(qs)
```

Comment: same thing. See i have a list with column name which vary from time to time. I don't know what is inside. just for understanding I had given . Finally i have a list. With the help of the list i want ordering.Now tell me how can i proceed with Django ORM.

Hope you remember my last question to get unique records from table based on a particular column. Now I want Django ORM such that it ll retrieve all the records & then start applying the ordering with the help of a list(listorder)

Comment: If you don't understand my Question then tell me explain more.

Comment: I think I have understood your question and your comment. This answer fits your question exactly.

Comment: Is it possible to apply ordering as a list to raw query sets or not?

Comment: Can you please reanswer the answer based on by Question. Like with raw query sets..Then that ll be great because i am confused how to implement this with Django ORM raw query set.

Comment: updated answer. Really this is all there is to it, no further explanation needed please try it out and you will see.